# sgadmin.sh failed elasticsearch && searchguard

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, search-guard

While trying to exucte

```
./sgadmin.sh -ts truststore.jks -tspass 90f3cbdb3eabe04f815b -ks CN=sgadmin-keystore.jks -kspass a65d2a4fa62d7ed7a4d5 -h host -p 9200 -nhnv -cn eslcl1 -cd ../sgconfig/
```

I am getting the following error:

Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{6PPXnCNqTt-W5g-0fmeZuQ}{host}{host:9200}]. This is not an error, will keep on trying

error:

```
WARNING: JAVA_HOME not set, will use /usr/bin/java
Search Guard Admin v5
WARNING: Seems you want connect to the a HTTP port.
     sgadmin connect through the transport port which is normally 9300.
Will connect to host:9200 ... done

### LICENSE NOTICE Search Guard ###

If you use one or more of the following features in production
make sure you have a valid Search Guard license
(See https://floragunn.com/searchguard-validate-license)

* Kibana Multitenancy
* LDAP authentication/authorization
* Active Directory authentication/authorization
* REST Management API
* JSON Web Token (JWT) authentication/authorization
* Kerberos authentication/authorization
* Document- and Fieldlevel Security (DLS/FLS)
* Auditlogging

In case of any doubt mail to <sales@floragunn.com>
###################################
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'eslcl1' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate     ...
Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: None of the configured nodes are     available: [{#transport#-1}{6PPXnCNqTt-W5g-0fmeZuQ}{host}{host:9200}]. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
Root cause: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{6PPXnCNqTt-W5g-0fmeZuQ}{host}{host:9200}]] (org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException/org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException)
* Try running sgadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If thats works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your SSL certificates)
* Make also sure that your keystore or cert is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in elasticsearch.yml
* If this is not working, try running sgadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
* Add --accept-red-cluster to allow sgadmin to operate on a red cluster.
```

My conf in elasticsearch.yml is

```
######## Start Search Guard Demo Configuration ########
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath: CN=x.x.x.x-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.keystore_password: 8a17368ff585a2c3afdc
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.transport.truststore_password: 90f3cbdb3eabe04f815b
searchguard.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
searchguard.ssl.http.enabled: false
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_filepath: CN=x.x.x.x-keystore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.keystore_password: 8a17368ff585a2c3afdc
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_filepath: truststore.jks
searchguard.ssl.http.truststore_password: 90f3cbdb3eabe04f815b
searchguard.authcz.admin_dn:
- CN=sgadmin

cluster.name: eslcl1
network.host: x.x.x.x
```

Is there any configuration that I might need to look into ?

Comment: Is it possible to have that `CN=` prefix for the `ks` value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to connect to port 9300 (the transport protocol), not 9200 which is typically the HTTP/S port. On port 9300 the elasticsearch nodes talk to each other through a binary TCP protocol. On port 9200 the REST api is accessible via HTTP/S.

sgadmin connect through the binary TCP protocol to elasticsearch, so you need to use port 9300.

Therefore you get this warning

```
WARNING: Seems you want connect to the a HTTP port.
     sgadmin connect through the transport port which is normally 9300.
```

So your command should look like

```
./sgadmin.sh -ts truststore.jks -tspass 90f3cbdb3eabe04f815b -ks CN=sgadmin-keystore.jks -kspass a65d2a4fa62d7ed7a4d5 -h host -p 9300 -nhnv -cn eslcl1 -cd ../sgconfig/ -nhnv
```

(Add -nhnv to disable hostname verification if your certificates are not matching your hostnames)